# Issues while sending emails using Laravel…

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

When sending the email, it is not formatting it correctly, it is displaying it in plain text and not using the HTML my view has in it.

The way I send it:

```
Mail::to($request->user()->mail)->send(new AccountLocked(Auth::user()));
```

AccountLocked.php:

```
class AccountLocked extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.user.account_locked');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an issue with Laravel, if you actually view the data being sent in the request you'll see Laravel **will** format the email properly, with a valid HTML code.

This issue is probably the targets email provider blocking the HTML, I know a few email providers that do this, you may want to check that before thinking its Laravel.